# Pointer/reference *& operator overload

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, overloading, operator-keyword

I am new using c++ and browsing some source code I found that code in a class.

```
SDL_Surface *m_srf;
//...
operator SDL_Surface*&()
{
    return m_srf;
}
```

It overloads both pointer (*) and reference or mem adress (&) operators?

Comment: I would, if I were you, be skeptical of the quality of the codebase where you saw this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a *conversion operator*: a member operator called `Class::operator Type()` can be used to convert an object of type `Class` to an object of type `Type`.

In this case, it converts to a reference to a pointer to `SDL_Surface`. So you can use this class wherever that type is required:

```
void set(SDL_Surface*& s) {s = whatever;}  // needs a reference
void do_something(SDL_Surface*);           // needs a pointer

my_class thingy;
set(thingy);          // OK - sets thingy.m_srf
do_something(thingy); // OK - passes thingy.m_srf to the function
```

Answer (score 3):

It's a conversion operator. It performs conversions to the type `SDL_Surface*&`, id est, the type of references to pointers to `SDL_Surface`.

Answer (score 1):

It is a conversion that convertst the object into a reference to a pointer to SDL_Surface.